# jquery conflicts even after use noConflict function

Tags: jquery

Please see my jquery code.

there is 3 click function. 1 after click slideToggle menu, 2nd click anywhere document, close the menu, 3rd one, click rotate class tigger class down.

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        // Dropdown toggle
        $('.rs-dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
          $(this).next('.rs-dropdown').slideToggle('slow');
        });

        $(document).click(function(e) {
          var target = e.target;
          if (!$(target).is('.rs-dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.rs-dropdown-toggle')) {
            $('.rs-dropdown').slideUp();
          }
        });

    });
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function( $ ) {
        $(".rotate").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("down"); 
        });
    })( jQuery );
</script>
```

Here is HTML Code:

```
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="rs-float-menu" class="rs-dropdown-toggle">
                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/add.png" class="rs-img"/>
            </a>
            <ul class="rs-dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="#"><div class="fa fa-chevron-up rotate"></div></a>
```

Without this jquery function the dropdown works fine, but when I use this, dropdown stopped working..

```
jQuery.noConflict();
    (function( $ ) {
        $(".rotate").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("down"); 
        });
    })( jQuery );
```

& console show this.. but the 2nd code work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/3v2egwfs/7/

[image: console error]

I don't understand where is the problem ! I believe I'm doing some silly mistake

Comment: Why are you  using `noConflict()` for some of the code and not all of it? Or why are you using it at all? What is specific problem?  What errors are thrown? Need more clarification if you want help

Comment: Describe what's actually happening. Why do you use `noConflict` after you've already used `$`?  WHat makes you think there's a conflict?

Comment: @DaveNewton I added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you added `noConflict()` for the wrong reasons and your whole problem was that the last event listener was not inside the *`document.ready`* handler. If the script tag is in the head you would have been running your code before element exists

Try

```
$(function() {
    // Dropdown toggle
    $('.rs-dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
      $(this).next('.rs-dropdown').slideToggle('slow');
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      var target = e.target;
      if (!$(target).is('.rs-dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.rs-dropdown-toggle')) {
        $('.rs-dropdown').slideUp();
      }
    });
    // moved inside the ready handler
    $(".rotate").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("down"); 
    });

});
```

Comment: It's work ! Thanks. But now this jquery conflicts with others jquery & plugins that use jquery. is that possible make it unique for avoid no conflict with others.

Comment: Depends on what `conflicts` means? You really need to learn to be more specific with your problem statements

Comment: i just define the jquery version with noconflict ... now it's work...
  `var jq213 = jQuery.noConflict(true); `

Comment: My guess is you are needlessly including jQuery more than once in page. You never answered above why you need `noConflict` in the first place

Answer (score -5):

try

```
$.noConflict();
```

instead of

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose?

Comment: or it could be because of $(document).click(function(e)  and $(".rotate").click(function() both click functions